# Regex capture either whole line or if there is an optional character then capture also 2 capture groups

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I want to optionally capture two groups after optional character.
I have 2 possible data outputs, like this:

```
Subject: 2019.07.19 13:30:00 some.host.com 178899 Problem: Server is unavailable
Subject: 2019.07.19 13:28:29 some.host.com 178892 Problem: Server is unavailable; Resolved: 2019.07.19 14:49:29
```

My regex filter as follows:

```
"/Subject\: ([2-9]{1}[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}) ([a-zA-Z0-9._-]*) ([0-9]*) Problem\: (.*)/"
```

So far it works like this:

```
\1 = 2019.07.19
\2 = 13:30:00
\3 = some.host.com
\4 = 178899
\5 = Server is unavailable
```

And for second pattern:

```
\1 = 2019.07.19
\2 = 13:30:00
\3 = some.host.com
\4 = 178899
\5 = Server is unavailable; Resolved: 2019.07.19 14:49:29
```

I use this regex filter as follows:

```
echo  "$SUBJECT" | sed -E "s/Subject\: ([2-9]{1}[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}) ([a-zA-Z0-9._-]*) ([0-9]*) Problem\: (.*)/\1\2\3\4\5/"
```

What I want is to get for \5 group only text until optional ";" character so it would be "Server is unavailable"
And In case of optional ";" character, then also capture \6 and \7 to return "2019.07.19" and "14:49:29" accordingly.

For several hours I have tried playing with non-capturing groups and optional groups, but nothing works.

Could anyone help me with this challenging problem?

Upd:

```
PROBLEM_DATE=output[0]
PROBLEM_TIME=output[1]
PROBLEM_HOST=output[2]
PROBLEM_ID=output[3]
PROBLEM_DESC=output[4]
RESOLVED_DATE=output[5]
RESOLVED_TIME=output[6]
```

and then possibly manipulate this data, compare time, write to log file.

Update2:

I can tune the format of data a bit, if it will make things easier.
Yes, maybe I over complicated things, maybe it's better to re-format from this:

```
Subject: 2019.07.19 13:30:00 some.host.com 178899 Problem: Server is unavailable
Subject: 2019.07.19 13:28:29 some.host.com 178892 Problem: Server is unavailable; Resolved: 2019.07.19 14:49:29
```

To this:

```
Subject: 2019.07.19 13:30:00 some.host.com 178899 Problem: Server is unavailable
Subject: 2019.07.19 14:49:29 some.host.com 178892 Resolved: Server is unavailable
```

I understood, that what I tried to do was not the right way.

So I guess I can use the following regex with new data format:

```
"/Subject\: ([2-9]{1}[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}) ([a-zA-Z0-9._-]*) ([0-9]*) (?:Problem|Resolved)\: (.*)/"
```

I'm not sure of the structure "(?:Problem|Resolved)" is correct or not.

And then check if string contains word "Problem" or "Resolved" to take actions based on event.

Wouldn't sed give me the array output if I assign it to a variable?
I don't have access to my linux terminal right now, so can't check this.

Comment: Maybe something like https://regex101.com/r/EFvLku/1 will do.

Comment: Hi, nope.. shows invalid regular expression.I use it toward the echo command, like this:
echo  "$SUBJECT" | sed -E "s/Subject\: ([2-9]{1}[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}) ([a-zA-Z0-9._-]*) ([0-9]*) Problem\: (.*)/\1\2\3\4\5/"

Comment: I have updated the question to include missing info about sed -E command

Comment: can you Problem string span mutliline, can it have `\n` ?

Comment: No, it is always single line

Comment: @Vak014 you can try [`this`](https://regex101.com/r/tN8lwR/2/), this will work if string doesn't have `\n`

Comment: What is the final result you expect? sed used the way you did will concatenate the group values, do you really want that?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I wanted to assign the result to a variable and use it as array, for example: output=$(this regex) and then assign variables like this:
PROBLEM_DATE=output[0]
PROBLEM_TIME=output[1]
PROBLEM_HOST=output[2]
PROBLEM_ID=output[3]
PROBLEM_DESC=output[4]
RESOLVED_DATE=output[5]
RESOLVED_TIME=output[6]

and then possibly manupulate this data, save to log file. Will update this info to original question.

Comment: I can tune the format of data a bit, if it will make things easier.
Yes, maybe I over complicated things, maybe it's better to re-format from this:
Subject: 2019.07.19 13:30:00 some.host.com 178899 Problem: Server is unavailable
Subject: 2019.07.19 13:28:29 some.host.com 178892 Problem: Server is unavailable; Resolved: 2019.07.19 14:49:29

To this:
Subject: 2019.07.19 13:30:00 some.host.com 178899 Problem: Server is unavailable
Subject: 2019.07.19 14:49:29 some.host.com 178892 Resolved: Server is unavailable

I understood, that what I tried to do was not the right way.

Comment: Wouldn't sed give me the array output if I assign it to a variable?

Comment: No, it does not work like this. You might use several sed commands to match the whole string and capture what you want replacing with `\1` and using `-n` option with `p` flag to get all the data you need, or `awk` also seems quite a viable solution for several values.

Comment: I use grep -i to match 'Subject: ' - this way I get string.

Comment: and later I though of getting variables with single sed command.
And if it's not possible to get array of matched groups with sed, that is sad.

Comment: No, that's not sad it's completely reasonable. sed is for doing simple `s/old/new` on individual strings. Nether sed nor shell are designed to do general purpose text manipulation - that's what awk was designed to do and if for some reason you don't want to use awk then use perl or python or ruby or similar. You have the wrong expectations of what tools should be able to do (e.g. sed automatically populate shell arrays) because you're misunderstanding what the various tools were designed to do and which tools to use for which tasks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I just have found a solution. 
With sed output configured like this "\1|\2|\3|" it will produce a delimited string and then I simply split that string by "|" character to get array, which can be compared for correct array member count and then assign them to appropriate variable for later possible processing.

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                  

SUBJECT="Subject: 2019.07.19 13:30:00 some.host.com 178899 Problem: Server is unavailable"                   

OUTPUT=`echo "$SUBJECT" | sed -E 's/Subject\: ([2-9]{1}[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-
9]{2}) ([a-zA-Z0-9._-]*) ([0-9]*) Problem\: (.*)/\1|\2|\3|\4|\5|/'`                                          

echo "OUTPUT = $OUTPUT"                                                                                      

IFS='|'                                                                                                      
read -a RESULT <<< "$OUTPUT"                                                                                 

echo "${RESULT[0]}"                                                                                          
echo "${RESULT[1]}"                                                                                          
echo "${RESULT[2]}"                                                                                          
echo "${RESULT[3]}"                                                                                          
echo "${RESULT[4]}"
```

Output:

```
sh-4.4$ ./test.sh                                                                                            
OUTPUT = 2019.07.19|13:30:00|some.host.com|178899|Server is unavailable|                                     
2019.07.19                                                                                                   
13:30:00                                                                                                     
some.host.com                                                                                                
178899                                                                                                       
Server is unavailable
```

Update-1:

Changed interpreter instead of `...` to $(...) as suggested, and perhaps even better - surrounded them with double quotes.

```
OUTPUT="$(echo "$SUBJECT" | sed -E 's/Subject\: ([2-9]{1}[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[
0-9]{2}) ([a-zA-Z0-9._-]*) ([0-9]*) Problem\: (.*)/\1|\2|\3|\4|\5|/')"
```

What can be improved - is how string is split into array by delimiter |. I am looking now for a better method now, will update answer soon.

Update-2:

This is the desired solution. There is actually a larger script. This is only a part. It works and does what I wanted.

```
#!/bin/bash

SUBJECT="Subject: 2019.07.19 13:30:00 some.host.com 178899 Problem: Resolved: Server Problem:is unavailable"

OUTPUT="$(echo "$SUBJECT" | sed -E 's/Subject\: ([2-9]{1}[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[
0-9]{2}) ([a-zA-Z0-9._-]*) ([0-9]*) (Problem|Resolved)\: (.*)/\1|||\2|||\3|||\4|||\5|||\6/')"

IFS='|||'

read -a RESULT <<< "$OUTPUT"

if [ "${#RESULT[*]}" -eq '16' ];
then
  EVENT_DATE="${RESULT[0]}"
  EVENT_TIME="${RESULT[3]}"
  EVENT_HOST="${RESULT[6]}"
  EVENT_ID="${RESULT[9]}"
  EVENT_TYPE="${RESULT[12]}"
  EVENT_TEXT="${RESULT[15]}"

  echo "EVENT_DATE: $EVENT_DATE"
  echo "EVENT_TIME: $EVENT_TIME"
  echo "EVENT_HOST: $EVENT_HOST"
  echo "EVENT_ID:   $EVENT_ID"
  echo "EVENT_TYPE: $EVENT_TYPE"
  echo "EVENT_TEXT: $EVENT_TEXT"
fi
```

and the output:

```
EVENT_DATE: 2019.07.19
EVENT_TIME: 13:30:00
EVENT_HOST: some.host.com
EVENT_ID:   178899
EVENT_TYPE: Problem
EVENT_TEXT: Resolved: Server Problem:is unavailable
```

Comment: That has some issues (see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082, the `read -r` part of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219, and consider how it'll behave if a `|` appears in the input) and doesn't even attempt to solve the problem you asked about which is how to handle the "Resolved" statements that can appear in the input. There's no reason to escape `:` in a regexp btw, it's not a RE metachar, it's just literal.

Comment: Fixed "``...`` to $(...) even better to "$(...)", also made it to use "|||" as a delimiter. About ":" semicolons you are not correct. In particular this case not escaping them brakes array output from that regex.
Regarding read -r part - didn't get you you mean. That simply doesn't work.

Comment: I **am** correct about `:`s, `read -r` should be used unless you **need* to not use it, and using `|||` instead of `|` is a bandaid that introduces other issues. Post a new question that includes what you're going to do with your array if you'd like help doing whatever it is you're trying to do the right way.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/^Subject: (....\...\...) (..:..:..) (\S+) (\S+) Problem: ([^;]*)(; Resolved: (....\...\...) (..:..:..))?.*/PROBLEM_DATE=\1\nPROBLEM_TIME=\2\nPROBLEM_HOST="\3"\nPROBLEM_ID=\4\nPROBLEM_DESC="\5"\nRESOLVED_DATE=\7\nRESOLVED_TIME=\8/' <<<"$SUBJECT" >srcFile
. scrFile
```

Use pattern matching and back references to ouput required results to a file and then source that file.

N.B. Back references 7 and 8 are grouped in back reference 6 which is optional (?).

Comment: Hi, this is IO hungry system so I don't want to produce additional excessive IO load.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question but is this what you're trying to do (using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ cat tst.awk
match($0,/Subject: ([2-9]{1}[0-9]{3}(\.[0-9]{2}){2}) ([0-9]{2}(:[0-9]{2}){2}) ([[:alnum:]._-]+) ([0-9]+) (Problem|Resolved): (.*)/,a) {
    print "PROBLEM_DATE="  a[1]
    print "PROBLEM_TIME="  a[3]
    print "PROBLEM_HOST="  a[5]
    print "PROBLEM_ID="    a[6]
    print "PROBLEM_STATE=" a[7]
    print "PROBLEM_DESC="  a[8]
    print "---"
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
PROBLEM_DATE=2019.07.19
PROBLEM_TIME=13:30:00
PROBLEM_HOST=some.host.com
PROBLEM_ID=178899
PROBLEM_STATE=Problem
PROBLEM_DESC=Server is unavailable
---
PROBLEM_DATE=2019.07.19
PROBLEM_TIME=14:49:29
PROBLEM_HOST=some.host.com
PROBLEM_ID=178892
PROBLEM_STATE=Resolved
PROBLEM_DESC=Server is unavailable
---
```

The above was run on this input file:

```
$ cat file
Subject: 2019.07.19 13:30:00 some.host.com 178899 Problem: Server is unavailable
Subject: 2019.07.19 14:49:29 some.host.com 178892 Resolved: Server is unavailable
```

You said you want to compare timestamps and based on results write to a log file - just do all of that in awk, don't try to do it in shell.

Comment: Hi, I want it to be in shell script format. I like this for flexibility and ability to extend and improve later.

Comment: This IS it in shell script format. The guys who invented shell to create/destroy move files and processes and sequence calls to tools also invented awk for shell to call when it had to manipulate text. If you want flexibility and ability to extend and improve later, as well as efficiency, robustness, and clarity then **this** is your starting point.

Comment: Did you read the post? I mentioned, that I want them to be saved in variables for later processing and maybe additional logic, when I decide. So not just printed output to terminal. This is kind of awk script, not a shell script.

Comment: What's the difference between awk printing the data you want and sed printing the data you want? Why is a sed script OK but an awk script is not since they're both standard tools required in every UNIX installation?

Comment: Here's the significant problem with what you posted - it implies you're doing to have some kind of loop reading lines from some file, calling sed to process one line at a time and generate text that you'll then store in a shell array and then do something with those values. That is a horrible approach and not the way you're supposed to write shell scripts (see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)). You should really be doing the whole thing in awk.

Comment: I want a shell script, not an awk script, don't you get it?

Comment: It doesn't implies that. I have a grepped line string from file, not a file, and then I apply once sed on it, why you are imagining something what is not actually the case? Allright, this maybe a horrible approach. Can you summarize? Why and what is better to use instead of shell array? I only have there 5 values, what's the problem? I don't want to learn now 100 methods of how to do this, simply don't have time. If you underline keypoints, I might consider then.